# update local storage json.stringify

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have got a localStorage as JSON string. Which looks like:

```
{"ttl":15778500,"now":1426846074300,"id":"1","name":"I am","id":"69"}
```

I need to change only value for "id" and leave other ones as they are.

My code looks like:

```
 var dbget = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localStorage') || "0");
 dbget.id = 25;
```

But when I am trying to save it is not working.

```
 localStorage.setItem('localStorage', JSON.stringify(dbget));
```

Could you please suggest how I can do it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean "not working"? Does the value not get saved to localstorage? Or does a wrong value get saved? Do you get errors in the console?

Comment: I have found my issue here with having two id's. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JSON is incorrect and shouldn't have a duplicate ID:

```
{"ttl":15778500,"now":1426846074300,"id":"1","name":"I am","id2":"69"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have duplicate `id` in your json

It is because first time there is no json object and dbget has only `0`, which will cause error and no object added, try to change the initialization like,

```
// Add empty object {} in place of "0" -------------------------v
var dbget = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localStorage') || {} );
dbget.id = 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my original string with two id's:

```
{"ttl":15778500,"now":1426846074300,"id":"1","name":"I am","id":"69"}
```

When I changed one id to id2 it worked as supposed to.